# Does "ifconfig wlan0 dhcp status" work for Android?

Tags: networking, shell

I cannot get any response from an Android device (Android 4.2) to command "ifconfig wlan0 dhcp status"

Command "ifconfig wlan0" returns the following:

```
wlan0: ip 192.168.0.14 mask 255.255.254.0 flags [up broadcast running multicast]
```

Does Android support "dhcp status"?  If not, how can I find out **through a command** whether DHCP is enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [How] can I find out through a command whether DHCP is enabled?

Provided that [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) is setup in PC, execute:

```
adb shell dumpsys wifi
```

In the output locate the string *Configured networks*. Following that would be the info on all the saved Wi-Fi networks in your device. For each network, *inter alia* you would see a line with the string *IP assignment*. Based on your configuration for that netowrk, it would either show STATIC or DHCP.

**Note** that you must have root access if you intend to run *dumpsys wifi* on a device through a command-line app since ordinary apps are usually not privileged to access a dump of WifiService.

Here's the relevant screenshot captured for Android 4.2.1:

[image: IMG]

The findings are valid for stock Android 6.0.1 as well.

Aforesaid information however doesn't query whether the router itself is capable of running a DHCP server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. It is strange that I get a totally different response on my Android 4.2 device.  It is not remotely close to yours.  It starts with: WatchdogStatus: State: android.net.wifi.WifiWatchdogStateMachine$WatchdogDisabledState@425a2e30mWifiInfo: [null].  It has 30+ rec lines such as  rec[0]: time=04-02 05:54:34.939 state=DefaultState orgState=DriverUnloadedState what=69632(0x11000)

Comment: I don't know the reason. Is that all you get to see as output? I double checked again on Android 4.2.1 and 6.0.1 and results do not deviate from my answer. Which Android device are you using?

Comment: It is a product using a custom ROM.  I will check with regular Android device and report back later today.  Thank you for all the effort.

Comment: I tried it on my Moto G 2015 on Lollipop 6.0 and got an error... EDIT: Nevermind, I missed the part about root and I am not rooted at the moment.

Comment: It works.  Thank you.  Is there an equivalent way for Ethernet?  I have tried dumpsys ethernet and dumpsys eth0, and neither works.

Comment: Sorry, but neither of my devices has support for Ethernet, so that was all the help I could offer.

Answer (score 2):

The Android version of `ifconfig` is [very limited](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-kernel/09KXkkHQRAI) compared to it's full-blown Linux version. And most commands I tried like dhcpstatus do not work.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.  Is there an alternative to check the DHCP status?

Comment: I haven't found a command line alternative, only apps. Sorry.

Comment: @Hong you can always "move your acceptance" to another answer, if a better one comes up :) And you can also check [other posts with `ifconfig` and DHCP](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=ifconfig+dhcp), which might provide additional details.

Comment: @Izzy Thank you for the reminder. I thought people are less likely to try to answer a question that has an accepted answer.  Let me wait for a few more hours.